# Pressing a button created by inserting HTML

Tags: button, insert

I am compiling an unordered list of elements with data stored in a database.  Values 'qid' are associated with separate div elements; I have it so that when a div is clicked, this code is executed:

```
var liststring =
        '<li id="'+qid+'">'+
            '<button type="button" class="del" onclick="deleteQuestion(\''+qid+'\');" >X</button>'+
        '</li>';
$('ul').append(liststring);
```

This gives every appearance of working; the list item and the button appear.  However, if I go to click one of the buttons I inserted without refreshing the page, the button doesn't work at all, and I get this error on line 1 of my code, where I have the doctype declaration:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected Token ILLEGAL

Once I refresh the page, though (the list remains the same), the buttons work.  I use Chrome.

I'm not sure what's going on; I read in another thread about invisible characters, but I looked for them in my editor Notepad++, and didn't find any.

What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var liststring =
        '<li id="'+qid+'">'+
            '<button type="button" class="del" >X</button>'+
        '</li>';
$(liststring).click(function(){
    deleteQuestion(qid);
});
$('ul').append(liststring);
```